# In CMV how do I use identify on a wms?

Tags: wms, getfeatureinfo, configurable-map-viewer

I've added an wms operational layer, I wonder if it's possible to add identify support, any samples will be helpful

```
{
            type: 'wms',
            url: 'http://...../geoserver/service_name/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap',
            title: 'WMS Name',
            spatialReference: {
                wkid: 4326
            },
            options: {
                id: 'title',
                opacity: 1.0,
                visible: true,
                format: "png",
                spatialReference: {
                    wkid: 4326
                },
                visibleLayers: ['NAMESPACE:LAYER_NAME']
            },
            layerControlLayerInfos: {
                layerGroup: 'layer group name'
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This currently is not possible using the Identify widget that comes with CMV. A new custom widget or modifications to the Identify widget would be required.